# The numbered distances are 20 mm using eso-pic, regardless if I say "40 mm"

Tags: eso-pic

Using the very simple example:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,landscape,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage[texcoord,grid,gridunit=mm,gridcolor=gray!40,subgridcolor=green!40]{eso-pic}
\begin{document}
.
\end{document}
```

I want a numbered step size in the grid of 40 mm, but I get one of 20 mm.

[image: Figure illustrating the numbered grid step size I get]

What is it that I am doing wrong?

---

**Update:**

When adding

```
\gridSetup
  [mm]  % gridunit name
  {1mm} % gridunit
  {1}   % gridlabel factor
  {10}  % grid delta
  {40}  % grid Delta
  {1}   % gap
```

to the example code above,

I get two interesting phenomena:

(1)
The "green" steps change to 10 mm in the horisontal direction, but not in the vertical.

[image: Figure illustrating what describes as "Phenomena (1)"]

(2)
At the middle of the document, the vertical lines have run out since they are too densly spaced.

[image: Figure illustrating what describes as "Phenomena (2)"]

Comment: You've changed the colours, but you've not changed the dimensions. What did you expect?

Comment: I thought dimensions was the "!40" part. I could not find information in manuals, so I used examples online.

Comment: You mean in `gridcolor=gray!40,subgridcolor=green!40`?  Note that the key names are `gridcolor` and `subgridcolor`, as the names indicate they are for setting the colour of the grid. The `!` syntax is from `xcolor`, and is for colour mixing. In general you can do `<colour1>!<percentage>!<colur2>` to mix two colours. If just one colour is specified, as in `gray!40`, `white` is used as the second colour. Hence, `gray!40` mixes 40% gray and 60% white. More complicated expressions are also possible, if of interest see section 2.3.2 in the `xcolor` manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Werners answer is correct. But there seems to be a bug in `eso-pic`. Some code necessary to set up the grid properly is only executed once while loading the package. It should probably be in `\AtBeginDocument`. I added it here to make `\gridSetup` work as expected.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,final]{article}
\usepackage[texcoord,grid,gridunit=mm,gridcolor=gray!40,subgridcolor=green!40]{eso-pic}
\gridSetup[mm]{1mm}{1}{5}{40}{1}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  % code from eso-pic, executed during load, but needed to properly
  % setting up the grid
  \ifESO@texcoord
    \def\ESO@yoffsetI{\z@}\def\ESO@yoffsetII{-\paperheight}%
    \edef\ESO@griddeltaY{-\ESO@griddelta}\edef\ESO@gridDeltaY{-\ESO@gridDelta}%
  \else
    \def\ESO@yoffsetI{-\paperheight}\def\ESO@yoffsetII{\z@}%
    \edef\ESO@griddeltaY{\ESO@griddelta}\edef\ESO@gridDeltaY{\ESO@gridDelta}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Cool! I've learnt a lot from you all!

Answer (score 5):

When you choose `mm` as the `gridunit`, it has a default setup:

```
\gridSetup
  [mm]  % gridunit name
  {1mm} % gridunit
  {1}   % gridlabel factor
  {5}   % grid delta
  {20}  % grid Delta
  {1}   % gap
```

Here `20` (or the *grid Delta*) sets the jump between major grid lines. You can change this to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[texcoord,grid,gridunit=mm,gridcolor=gray!40,subgridcolor=green!40]{eso-pic}
\gridSetup
  [mm]  % gridunit name
  {1mm} % gridunit
  {1}   % gridlabel factor
  {5}   % grid delta
  {40}  % grid Delta
  {1}   % gap

\begin{document}  

.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool. Two follow-up questions: (1) Why is the screen shot you provided scaled differently in the horisontal and vertical axes? (2) What does the "{5}" mean here? The green steps in horisontal direction are 5 mm and in the vertical direction they are 10 mm.

Comment: I updated the original questions with what happens using the "\gridSetup". Partly related to my follow-up question actually.

Comment: @LarsAbrahamsson: You can vary the combinations of *gridlabelfactor* and *gridDelta*. For example, try 2 and 20.

Comment: Werner: Thanks. The _gridlabelfactor_ is simply a scaling, makes the document seems a different size than it actually is.

Comment: Werner: _grid_ _delta_ is the increments without numbers (green in the example). _grid_ _Delta_ on the other hand is the increments with numbers (gray in the example).

Comment: Werner: Those numbers does not affect the fact that in the vertical direction something goes "wrong", as shown in the figure I added when I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I added the correction (version 3.0b).

Comment: It might be good to extend the answer a little bit or just put it as a comment to the other answers.